# Почему VS 2012 выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Здравствуйте!

Интересный и абсолютно непонятный для меня факт, почему этот код выдаёт ошибку:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS"); /*выдаёт ошибку, если функция стоит первой*/

    int num;    
    num = 1;

    printf("Я простой ");
    printf("компьютер\n");
    printf("Моей любисой цифрой является %d, так как она первая\n",num);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: SprataC, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>  2.1.c
1>c:\users\zzz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\spratac\spratac\2.1.c(9): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "тип"
1>c:\users\zzz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\spratac\spratac\2.1.c(10): error C2065: num: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\zzz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\spratac\spratac\2.1.c(15): error C2065: num: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\zzz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\spratac\spratac\2.1.c(20): warning C4013: system: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

А если поставить функцию setlocale ниже, то ошибка пропадает и код прекрасно компилируется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{

    int num;    
    num = 1;

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");  /*ошибки нет*/

    printf("Я простой ");
    printf("компьютер\n");
    printf("Моей любисой цифрой является %d, так как она первая\n",num);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста: почему возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: 1.попробовать всё стереть и перепечатать ручками (вдруг беда с кодировками)

2.попробовать rus вместо RUS (хотя разницы нет)

3.попробовать подрубить без .h

4.попробовать подрубить iostream

но вообще действительно странно ... пойду ка скачаю 2012

Comment: Вообще там должны быть пустые кавычки setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, не помогли ваши методы, в VS 2010 те же самые ошибки. 3 и 4 способ не пробовал, пишу на СИ.  
@embarcadero, А почему пустые кавычки, как он поймёт язык? Ваш метод тоже не помог.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Visual Studio 2012` поддерживает [некоторое подмножество стандарта `C99,`](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/) и объявление переменных в произвольном месте блока не входит в него.
2. Проверить это можно еще проще:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
       {
           /* ... */
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ну вот, обидели VS 2010...

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему, компилятор хочет, чтобы переменные объявлялись в начале функции.

Если я не ошибаюсь, по стандарту в C89 переменные объявляются в начале блока. То есть функции или конструкции `{ ... }`.

В более новом стандарте C99 переменные уже можно объявлять как в C++ -- почти где угодно.

Comment: и что ещё остались компиляторы 89-го года? 

или майкрософт в VS2012 используют компилятор 89?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat: во-первых, C89 -- это не "стандарт 1989-го года". Во-вторых, вполне возможно, VS 2012 умеет компилировать код в различных стандартах, это может, например, настраиваться в свойствах проекта. Мне кажется, ваш минус необоснован.

---

Насчёт 1989 года беру свои слова назад. Тем не менее, это достаточно популярный стандарт языка.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat: Например, [Википедия](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#Compilers_supporting_ANSI_C) говорит, что MSVC поддерживает лишь малую часть C99.

Comment: @VladD, я склоняюсь к мнению, что видимо Си требует вначале объявить хоть одну переменную, а потом функцию из либы включать. Вы, наверное правы. Неудобно это, блин. ждём мнения крутых экспертов.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК: насколько я понимаю, используемый вами стандарт C хочет, чтобы _все_ переменные были объявлены в начале (функции или блока). Поройтесь в свойствах проекта, может быть, у вас заказана старая версия языка.

Comment: хмм я не претендую на истину в первой инстанции но вроде как его (89) начали стандартизировать в 89 от того и название (а вот когда закончили хз)

а по поводу Википедии будь осторожен, там часто бывают ошибки в виде недочётов(например не указали версию VS, и с момента постинга прошло много лет...),  ладно не будем холивар разводить...

Answer (score 0):

[@ВладиславМСК](/users/4878/%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA) видимо ты плохо проверял :) вот скрины в 2010, комментарии излишни

http://s001.radikal.ru/i196/1212/86/99896aabf806.jpg

http://s018.radikal.ru/i500/1212/a6/765c4dda0e46.jpg

http://s017.radikal.ru/i408/1212/d3/578ddd61a615.jpg

Comment: Хм, а у меня не работает, а функция system работает без проблем. Какие у вас настройки?

Comment: возможно ты не правильно создал проект под консоль...
[вот тут  смотри][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/143258/windows-visual-c-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=144597#144597

Comment: Я сделал всё правильно. Чудно. Может из-за ОС, у меня винда 8.

Comment: Насколько я помню, setlocale вообще в win не работает так как надо.

Используйте std::system("chcp 1251").

Comment: @manking  а что именно не работает?

@ВладиславМСК а через < cstdio > вместо stdio.h тоже ругается?

Comment: Сейчас попробовал:

setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus"); 
setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP1251" );


Обе работают и под visual 2012 и 2010.
Когда раньше проверял в 2010 не работали.
Не знаю с чем связано.